# Issue in create Two Column Layout

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have below code to divide a layout into 2 columns.

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1" style="height:230px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <lightning-radio-group name="country"
                               options={optionsCountry}
                               value={value}
                               type="radio"></lightning-radio-group><br/>
        <lightning-radio-group name="depot"
                               options={optionsDepot}
                               value={value}
                               type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>

    </div>
    <div class="column">
       <lightning-combobox
                    name="progress"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder="Select Progress"
                    options={optionsComboCountry}
                    onchange={handleChangeCountry} ></lightning-combobox><br/>
       <lightning-combobox
                    name="progress"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder="Select Progress"
                    options={optionsComboDepot}
                    onchange={handleChangeDepot} ></lightning-combobox>

    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          onchange={handleChange}></lightning-checkbox-group>
</div>
```

But I am getting the result like this.

[image]

I am not able to align it in same line. Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Alignment would be easier with lightning-layout and layoutItem

Comment: Thank you Rahul!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Raul said, this is done easily with lightning layout.

```
<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">Column 1 Content</lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">Column 2 Content</lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Comment: Thank you Taylor!!. Its working perfectly